# Building Eclipse project on new machine. GNU Linker cannot find library

Tags: gcc, arm, eclipse-cdt, ld

I have a CortexM0 project using a custom Makefile that builds and debugs successfully on a 1st machine.
Now trying to move the project to a second Mac.
Same version of Eclipse.

On build I get a linker error:

`EclipseApr2019/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_2-2015q4/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lg`

My make file looks like this (extract):

```
    @ echo "path="$(TOOLS)
    $(TOOLS)arm-none-eabi-gcc -n -v -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -g -nostartfiles -T STM32F031C6_simple.ld  main.c  StartUp_simple.s -o $(NAME).elf
```

I have tried to append the ARM gcc tools directory to the PATH variable in the Project, but no luck.

I would add a -l option to the link stage in the makefile, but do not know why this library is being pulled in or where it is. My code only does a series of shifts and reads/writes to registers on an MCU. The build on the 1st machine worked fine without specifying a library location like this.

Given I have custom makefile and am not generating Makefile automatically, there are no tool settings (and Library search path) available under Properties/CC++Build/Settings.

- What is library "g" that the linker is pulling in?
- Where is it?
- Under Eclipse, how can I point the linker to the library?
- Why didn't I need to do that before?
- What is some general advice for designing an Eclipse project with a custom makefile to make it most portable between machines?

Thank you.

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)

Comment: There is no -lg on the command line, and libg is not a default library gcc usually needs. Check the makefile on your second machine again. Look at the actual commands being ran. Leave Eclipse alone, it is not your friend and is not relevant here in any case. Run make from the terminal.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I ran make - f Makefile from the command line. Unfortunately same result.

Comment: How can it be different if you are running the same command? However you are supposed to, I quote, *Look at the actual commands being ran*. Command result is a bit useless without knowing what the command is, right?

Comment: Indeed. I agree. That was why I ran verbose mode -v in the makefile command.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Finally fixed; as you alluded, the issue was beyond Eclipse and was in the underlying tools where I had forgotten to include the gcc path in my PATH variable.